# How treat columns with colons in SQL

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

What is the correct syntax in SQL so that it accepts colons in my column names?

I'm trying to query a Data Extension that was created from a Journey's Salesforce Data Entry source. Consequently, the column names include colons by default.

Below is an example of a portion of the query. I've tried with validating the columns with [], with '', and without anything at all, but it's serving me up validation errors - mainly "Errors: Incorrect syntax near 'Request__c:'."

```
SELECT
  [request.Request__c:Id]
, request.Request__c:Booker_Contact__r:Email
, 'request.Request__c:Booker_Contact__r:FirstName' 

FROM Request_Adjustment_Master_Homelike adjustment
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your data extension?

Comment: You need to put brackets around every field that has a : in it. I just tested this and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested this syntax and it works

```
Select [Contact:Id], 
[Contact:LastName], 
[Contact:et4ae5__HasOptedOutOfMobile__c]
from [syntaxtest - 2017-07-14T152814271]
```

So simply put brackets around any field with a `:`